# Generic API publishing techniques

Tags: c++, api, user-interface, interface

I'm designing the next generation of a framework architecture for an internal project. Essentially there is a run time system that provides an API to applications which can be loaded/unloaded on the fly.

In the framework lives a library of custom "devices" The current interface to these devices is extremely generic; think posix load/unload/read/write/etc... One of the important principles of the framework is that the Apps need to know very little about device specifics.

Unfortunately, this interface has broken down to where the application developers end up rewriting common functions in the application itself.

I'm looking for suggestions or even a place to start reading about designing framework APIs like this. What is a good set of tools that a "device" author in the framework can use to publish an interface? What is the best way *to* publish an interface?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is lacking in the current system, driving application developers to abandon it?  What kind of API functions would you need to add, and if they're added alongisde the load/unload/read/write ones there already, what problem would that cause?

Comment: The current system is too generic. I might create one device that does signal processing and another that is a motor controller. The only interface methods I can use to publish are things like load/unload/read/write, etc... I want the device author to be able to publish their own custom method/functions for that device but allow the App to not necessarily need to #include anything extra. They should be able to query the framework for installed devices and then get the interface the device author published.

Comment: So, say the App doesn't include anything extra and can find out about and potentially call the extra functions, how's it going to *decide whether/when* to call them, and what to do with the results?  Is the unchanged App going to read input from somewhere (e.g. a config file, keyboard or UI widget) specifying calls to those functions, or would the App be edited to specify calls?

Comment: The App developer will know what device he is trying to talk to. He will know in a paper document (ICD) how to talk to the device. So the app will have code that depends on knowledge of the device. The only thing that is important to decouple is the runtime-linkable app module requiring certain specific calls that cannot be resolved at link time. The specific device API should be managed and made available by the framework itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - a proposal - may be vastly different from what you wanted, but feedback will help home in on something useful.

For synchronous "calls" you want your app module to send an indication of the driver function required and however many arguments, then retrieve some result.  That can be achieved in a generic way by have a second, distinct read/write stream over which an encoding of the function and values is transmitted.  So, say the driver API includes:

```
string get_stuff(string x, int y, double d[]);
```

This is NOT code - it's text that the framework/app can print/parse and potentially use to verify that data is sent and consumed correspondingly.

The app module then writes a "call" to the driver as a stream of function identifier and inputs, followed by a read of the result (assuming the app module has same-named variables holding the desired parameter values).

```
driver_api << "get_stuff " << escape(x) << ' ' << y << " [" << d.size() << "] ";
for (auto i = d.begin(); i != d.end(); ++i)
    driver_api << ' ' << *i;
driver_api << '\n';

std::getline(driver_api, result);
```

It's a little more work (half an hour?) to create a custom stream wrapper that can wrap `driver_api` and insert the spaces or other separators/delimiters above, support streaming of containers, and/or send the data in a binary form, letting you write a cleaner and/or faster value-oriented version of the above, something like:

```
(driver_api << "get_stuff" << x << y << d) >> result;
```

You could also write normal C++ functions to wrap the above for the app module to call:

```
string get_stuff(const std::string& x, int y, const std::vector<double>& d)
{
    string result;
    (driver_api_ << "get_stuff" << x << y << d) >> result;
    return result;
}
```

On the driver side, you'd write matching deserialisation routines to recover the app module specified values from the stream.

For specific architectures you may be able to get libraries to allow more convenient calls to functions, utilising debug information or ABI knowledge etc, whereas the above only needs Standard C++ and can be written to be portable (with a little care if doing binary serialisation of endian values).

EDIT - example of binary serialisation (just output for now / runs but output not carefully inspected for validity / most things fixed-width but strings are NUL terminated and containers prefixed by size / doesn't send following-field type information but very easy to create a version that does):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <winsock2.h>
typedef signed char int8_t;
typedef signed short int16_t;
typedef signed int32_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned uint32_t;

class Binary_IOStream
{
  public:
    Binary_IOStream(std::istream& i, std::ostream& s) : i_(i), s_(s) { }
    typedef Binary_IOStream This;
    This& operator<<(int8_t x) { return write(x); }
    This& operator<<(int16_t x) { return write(htons(x)); }
    This& operator<<(int32_t x) { return write(htonl(x)); }
    This& operator<<(uint8_t x) { return write(x); }
    This& operator<<(uint16_t x) { return write(htons(x)); }
    This& operator<<(uint32_t x) { return write(htonl(x)); }
    This& operator<<(const std::string& s)
        { s_.write(s.c_str(), s.size() + 1); // include NUL, but could size-prefix
          return *this; }
    This& operator<<(double x) { return write(x); }

    template <typename T>
    This& operator<<(const std::vector<T>& v)
        { return write_range(v.begin(), v.end()); }

    template <typename Iterator>
    This& write_range(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    {
        operator<<(std::distance(begin, end));
        while (begin != end)
            operator<<(*begin++);
        return *this;
    }

  private:
    template <typename T>
    This& write(const T& t)
        { s_.write((const char*)&t, sizeof t); return *this; }

    std::istream& i_;
    std::ostream& s_;
};

int main()
{
    Binary_IOStream bs(std::cin, std::cout);

    bs << ('A' << 24) + ('b' << 16) + ('c' << 8) + 'D';
    bs << "hello world!";
    std::vector<double> v;
    v.push_back(3.14);
    v.push_back(2.72);
    bs << v;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the idea I had in mind as well. Can you suggest any standard way of encoding the call into a stream? Something that is fast (I don't want a bunch of xml wrappers) preferably with the raw data in a native format but standard that I might be able to grab a c/c++ library for.

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but I'll edit in a bit of code illustrating how it can be done.

Comment: I think I understand your proposal completely. I could code something like that up right now, no problem. It would be nice if there was a standard way to do this. I almost can't believe there isn't. I think that is the next step of my search. I know JSON does something like this but JSON is not fast enough (it encodes ascii string data) I want something that puts as little into the stream as possible and makes building/deconstructing the stream very fast because the encoded data is already in the native format.

Comment: @Lother: have editing in enough to hopefully kick start things for you.  I'd be amazed if there's not a library around somewhere... I've written the same thing for companies in the past, but not OSS.  Someone must have.  Alternatively, at a higher level that per-variable binary serialisation, there're solution like Google protobuf... that might of interest.

Comment: Tony, Thank you. That is a clever implementation. If I don't find a library for this (I'll take a look at protobuf soon) I will most certainly use what you have provided. Just having this conversation with you has been extremely insightful. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lother: you're welcome... hope it goes well.  Cheers.